# 256 bits output Hash Function on Java

Tags: java, hash

Can someone please point me out a **hash function**(preferably an implementation) which would let me have **256 bits string outputs** for the given string?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: SHA-256?........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageDigest md   = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); //make sure it exists, there are other algorithms, but I prefer SHA for simple and relatively quick hashing
String strToEncode = "Hello world";
md.update(strToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8")); //I'd rather specify the encoding. It's platform dependent otherwise. 
byte[] digestBuff = md.digest();
```

*digestBuff* will contain the digested bytes.

Comment: It produces a SHA-256 hash. I don't know the details but I hope I will someday.

Comment: @BPL: what kind of details are you after?  The API is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html.  The specific hash is described at e.g. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2.

Comment: Thank you very much guys: We got our answer.